# ¿Cómo y porque un bucle WHILE pueda leer un array asociativo, numérico o ambos?

Tags: php, array, while

Quisiera saber porque y cómo el bucle WHiLE lee un array, ya que estaba haciendo pruebas para un crud en la cual con base a un formulario de buscar (por ejemplo, datos de una familia), dependiendo de los registros me los agrupara en filas, es decir, dependiendo de que valores se podrán en los campos del formulario, me mostrará uno o varias filas con los datos de la familia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ven me arrojo dos resultados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aquí en este caso me arrojo uno

Al principio lo intente que un bucle FOR pero no funcionó hasta que con un WHILE si les los mostro, y como tal tengo esa duda, de porque un WHILE pueda tomar como condición un array, ¿Cómo y porque?

Código para su explicacíon.

```php
    <?php
      
     $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
     $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
     $edad=$_POST['edad'];
     $gusto=$_POST['gusto'];
     
     $sql="SELECT Nombres,P_Apellido,S_apellido,Edad,Gusto FROM miembros WHERE 
     Nombres='$nombre'and P_Apellido='$apellido' or Edad='$edad' or Gusto='$gusto'";

     $buscar=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

     echo "<table border=1>".
       "<tr>".
              "<th>"."Nombre"."</th>".
              "<th>"."Primer apellido"."</th>".
              "<th>"."Segundo apellido"."</th>".
              "<th>"."Edad"."</th>".
              "<th>"."Gusto"."</th>".
       "</tr>";

       while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)){
           echo "<tr>".
                   "<td>".$fila['Nombres']."</td>".
                   "<td>".$fila['P_Apellido']."</td>".
                   "<td>".$fila['Edad']."</td>".
                   "<td>".$fila['Gusto']."</td>".
                "</tr>";
       }

      ?>
```

Comment: No entendí la pregunta. ¿Cuál es tu problema concretamente?

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Cómo estaba construido el código usando for? Añádelo a tu pregunta usando la opción [edit]

Comment: Como tal es resolverme esa una duda de ¿Cómo y porque un while pueda tener como condición un array?, tengo entendido que los while funcionan si una condición es verdadera o falsa

Comment: Correcto, el [`while`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.while.php) es un bucle, que se ejecuta mientras una condición se cumpla. Entonces, ¿cuál es el problema concretamente aquí?

Comment: Si traduces más o menos literalmente la cosa seria "Mientras recorres cada uno de los elementos del recurso de mysqli y lo devuelves como un array entonces asígnalo a la variable $fila"... y cuando ya no pueda hacerlo, porque no le queden elementos, entonces parará (es un poco bruto, pero yo lo entiendo así)... si quieres el true seria mientras haya elementos, y el false cuando no quede ninguno

Comment: Se supone que los arrays no pueden ser tomados como condición para un while

Comment: No es un array, es un [recurso](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.resource.php) mysqli que contiene elementos que puede devolver como array (asociativo o no) o como objeto segun el `fetch` que uses

Comment: Dentro del `while` lo que verificas es el resultado de esta llamada: `mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)` **mientras sea verdadero, o sea, mientras haya filas**. No es un array como tal, el array se crea en `$fila` mediante asignación.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Es decir, repetirá las instrucciones hasta que vaya al ultimo indice del array

Answer (score 1):

> Se supone que los arrays no pueden ser tomados como condición para un
> while

En esta línea de código:

```
   while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)){
```

Tú no estás tomando **necesariamente** un array como condición de un `while`, sino **lo que hay en tu variable `$fila`**, y eso **puede ser un array** o **pueder ser `null`**, como veremos.

Si lees [la documentación verás que `mysqli_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o
> ambos.

Y en **Valores devueltos** dice (atención a los **dos posibles valores** de devolución):

> Retorna un array de strings que corresponde a la fila obtenida o null
> si no hay más filas en el resultset.

Por tanto, lo que aquí ocurre:

```
   while ($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar)){
```

Es lo siguiente:

- Se asigna a `$fila` el resultado de `mysqli_fetch_array`, que **puede** ser un array o **puede** ser `null`.
- Se usa `$fila` dentro del `while`
- El `while` **se ejecutará mientras `$fila` sea evaluado como `true`**, o lo que es lo mismo, mientras `$fila` tenga algún dato, o lo que es lo mismo, **se detendrá** cuando ya no haya filas en el puntero, o lo que es lo mismo, se detendrá cuando `$fila` sea `null` según la definición del método que estás usando en este caso para la asignación.

Para hacer una prueba de esto, tú pudes crear un array cualquiera y **evaluarlo de este modo**:

```
$fila=array("Nombre"=>"Juan); #Una fila cualquiera del puntero

if($fila) {
    //Se cumple, porque $fila tiene datos
}

$fila=null; #Esto es lo que ocurre cuando no hay más filas en el puntero de mysqli

if($fila) {
    //No se cumple, porque $fila es null
}
```

### Recomendaciones:

- `mysqli_fetch_array` **te trae los datos dos veces**, como array asociativo y como array numérico. Para este caso, considera mejor usar [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) que te los traerá sólo como array asociativo, que es el uso que estás dando en la lectura.
- Tu consulta SQL es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *inyección SQL*. Considera blindar tu código implementando **consultas preparadas**. Mediante un ataque de *inyección SQL* un usuario puede causar verdaderos estragos en tu sistema. Desde obtener datos ilícitos, manipularlos, modificarlos... hasta introducir archivos maliciosos en el sistema. Sí, desde SQL, en algunos contextos, hay formas de crear archivos y guardarlos en el servidor.